# FileHelpers CSV timespan

Tags: f#, filehelpers

I'm parsing a CSV with the fileHelpers module in F#. Was wondering what the best approach to converting a time to the best format. I assumed the best format would be a timeSpan, however can't find a convertKind for the timespan

if i had a string e.g. 10:05.0
This would represent 10:05 am. What would be the best way to use ConvertKind with the FileHelpers Library to parse this string into a structure that represented 10:05

thanks for all the help!

Comment: if always "hh:mm.0" then TimeSpan.TryParse("10:05.0".Replace('.',':'))

Answer (score 2):

You could implement your conversion in a custom Converter (inherit [ConverterBase](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.ConverterBase.html)), then [use it in your FieldConverter attribute](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FieldConverterAttributeConstructor9.html)

Comment: Thats the solution, use your own Converter. check this example: http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/example_customconv.html